# How to Unzip a file in ios6?

Tags: iphone, ios6, unzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [download and unzip file in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333399/download-and-unzip-file-in-ios)

I want to unzip file in my application. I searching many things some of them told to use ZipArchive Library. There is any default methods are available in ios6.

Comment: … or [How to download & unzip files on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605545/how-to-download-unzip-files-on-ios).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in iOS 6 that does zip/unzip. See one of the many existing threads on SO that cover this topic (ZipArchive, Objective-Zip, etc.).

Comment: @maddy We cannot use the zipArchive in ios6. bcoz lot of linker errors are produced

Answer (score 0):

[zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) is a new comer. Features:

- **Easy-to-use interface**: The public API offers just three classes! Yet you can look through zip files using familiar *NSArray* collections and properties. And you can zip, unzip and rezip zip files through familiar *NSData*, *NSStream* and Image I/O classes.
- **Efficient implementation**: We've optimized zip file reading and writing to reduce virtual memory pressure and disk file thrashing. Depending on how your compound document is organized, updating a single entry can be faster than writing the same data to a separate file.
- **File format compatibility**: Since *zipzap* closely follows the [zip file format specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), it is works with most Mac, Linux and Windows zip tools.